# How to send a list of data to Controller Action method using jQuery ajax method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Here is my Action Mehtod

```
public JsonResult GetById(IEnumerable<Guid> idList)
    {

        //.....
    }
```

And my JavaScript . I'm making an array of strings using  **li** element's id property

```
var idArr = [];
        var list = $("#ulApplications li");
        $.each(list, function () {  idArr.push($(this).attr("id")) });          


        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/rolemanagement/application/GetById/",
                contentType: false,
                datatype: "json",
                data: { 'idList': idArr },
                success:........
```

On my Action method I'm not getting any data.It seems I'm Missing something.
thanks

Comment: It is trying to map the URL's querystring to a list of GUIDs, which is messy to say the least :) Use `post` with your array instead to simplify this. Just use `data: idArr` and it should map the only data item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your ajax to

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/rolemanagement/application/GetById", // should use '@Url.Action(..)'
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify({ idList: idArr }), // stringify
  success: ....
})
```

Comment: Still not working,I think default model binder is not able to convert the received data into a list of Guid.

Comment: Are the values valid GUID's? Try changing it to `IEnumerable<string> idList` (must admit I have never tried to pass GUID's to a controller)

Comment: Also for testing, create a dummy list in the client, say `var idArr = ["Item 1", "Item 2"];`

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the below code which seems to be working fine,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetById", new { area = "rolemanagement", controller = "application"})",
    data: { idList: [{ a: 'a' }, { a: 'b' }] },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { console.log(data); },
    error: function () { throw new Error("Error occurred."); }
});
```

which already given by @stephen where even stringify is not even required to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

After searching on stackoverflow and other blogs. I found a solution which is working for me, although above given answers are closely correct but they didn't worked for me. Here is my answer

```
var IdList = {idList:idArr}

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/rolemanagement/application/GetById/",
                contentType: false,
                datatype: "json",
                data: IdList,
                traditional: true,
                success:
                    function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
```