# Passing array to MVC controller via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Trying to pass a list of objects to my MVC controller from my jquery script. The controller ain't getting the list. Any ideas?

**Script**

```
function refreshXeroData(obj, planId, date, list) {
    // list comes in as a serialized array
    // list = "[{"Id":245225,"XeroFromDate":"4/22/2015 12:00:00 AM","XeroToDate":""},{"Id":245226,"XeroFromDate":"4/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","XeroToDate":"4/30/2016 12:00:00 AM"}]"

    var model = { PlanId: planId, Date: date, List: list };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: model,
        success: function (data) {
            // code removed for clarity
        },
     });
 }
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Refresh(int planId, DateTime date, List<XeroScenarioModel> list)
{
    // list is null
    // code removed for clarity
}
```

**Model**

```
public class XeroScenarioModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string XeroFromDate { get; set; }
    public string XeroToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First I'd try data: JSON.stringify(model) in the ajax, sometimes that helps.  Next I'd look closer at the date.  I doubt you'll be able to map the javascript date onto a C# DateTime object.  I'd probably create that object with it's date parts (month, day, year, each as separate values) and then create the DateTime object in the controller based on those values.

Comment: If you're sending the list as an already serialized string, the MVC model binder is probably interpreting it as a `string` not a `List`.  Try `json_decode` on the list string before adding it to the model.

Comment: Add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and change it to `data: JSON.stringify(model)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a list of data to Controller Action method using jQuery ajax method in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422502/how-to-send-a-list-of-data-to-controller-action-method-using-jquery-ajax-method)

Comment: @jmoerdyk lead me on the right path...I used json.Parse() on the list before I passed it in. All good :).

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code try the code mentioned below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshXeroData() {
    // list comes in as a serialized array
    var planId = 1234;
    var date = new Date();
    list = '[{"Id":245225,"XeroFromDate":"4/22/2015 12:00:00 AM","XeroToDate":"4/30/2016 12:00:00 AM"},{"Id":245226,"XeroFromDate":"4/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","XeroToDate":"4/30/2016 12:00:00 AM"}]';

    var model = { planId: planId, date: "4/30/2016 12:00:00 AM", list: JSON.parse(list) };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../Sample/Refresh',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            // code removed for clarity
        },
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used JSON.parse() on the array being passed in.

```
// list = "[{"Id":245225,"XeroFromDate":"4/22/2015 12:00:00 AM","XeroToDate":""},{"Id":245226,"XeroFromDate":"4/1/2016 12:00:00 AM","XeroToDate":"4/30/2016 12:00:00 AM"}]"
var model = { PlanId: planId, Date: date, List: JSON.parse(list) };

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url,
   data: model,
   success: function (data) {
       // code removed for clarity
   },
});
```

No need for JSON.stringify().